# How to only get items that have not sold in the past 30 days?

Tags: sql

I need to find items that have not sold in the past 30 days.

I can get items that have sold, but I don't know where to start when finding items that have not sold.

```
SELECT
    ITEMNMBR
FROM 
    SOP10100

WHERE 
    ORDRDATE>= DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation:

```
SELECT ITEMNMBR
FROM SOP10100
GROUP BY ITEMNMBR
WHERE MAX(ORDRDATE) < DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE())
```